# Efficiency Analysis of Two Different Implementations of Insertion Sort

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I came up with two implementations for a simple insertion sort algorithm in Python. My question: Is the second implementation more efficient than the first? Because it seems like that in the first implementation, for every iteration of the while loop, the program has to perform two assignments: `list[i]` gets assigned to `list[i-1]` and vice versa (apart from decrementing `i` by 1).

```
def insertion1(list):

    for i in range(1,len(list)):     

        while i >= 1 and list[i] < list[i-1]:
            list[i],list[i-1] = list[i-1],list[i]
            i -= 1
```

But in the second implementation the program has to make only one assignment for every iteration of the while loop: `list[index + 1] = list[index]` (again apart from decrementing `index` by 1 and one additional assignment after the termination of the while loop: `list[index + 1] = temp`).

```
def insertion2(list):

    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        temp = list[i]
        index = i - 1

        while index >= 0 and list[index] > temp:
            list[index + 1] = list[index]
            index -= 1
        list[index + 1] = temp
```

Does this mean that `insertion1` roughly has to make twice as many assignment statements compared to `insertion2`, making `insertion2` the more accurate implementation of insertion sort?

Comment: wdum by "accurate implementation"?

Comment: You could do some timings and see, but as a side note, you shouldn't use `list`, which is a Python builtin function, as variable name, that shadows its original meaning.

Comment: @Ecto What do you mean by 'wdum'? There are many people here whose first language isn't English, and some abbreviations might not be evident for all of us... ;)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Algorithm 1 is roughly half as fast compared to algorithm 2. So my reasoning should be correct?

Comment: @Ecto : I mean that insertion sort is usually explained in terms of reassigning all the values and only reassigning `temp` after completion of going through the whole list, not in terms of switching values after each comparison.

Comment: @MoritzWolff The switching is usually mentioned only in pseudocode, in actual implementations is almost always used your insertion2, as it's obviously more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. However, even the `insertion2` is suboptimal. The inner loop does 2 *comparisons* per iteration (`index >= 0` and `list[index] > temp`). It is possible to reduce it to (almost) one comparison:

```
    if temp < list[0]:
        # We don't care about values anymore. Every element shall be shifted.
        while index >= 0:
            list[index + 1] = list[index]
            index -= 1
    else:
        # We don't care about indices anymore. list[0] is a natural sentinel
        while temp < list[index]:
            list[index + 1] = list[index]
            index -= 1
    list[index] = temp
```